# Compressing selected js folder using yui compressor in Maven

Tags: maven, plugins, yui-compressor

I am trying to compress only js in selected folder in my webapp(impl/amss9/widgets) directory using following code

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                         <includes>
                            <include>${amss.webapp.dir}/impl/amss9/widgets/**/*.js</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>   
        </plugin>
```

The above code is not compressing anything.
If I remove includes tag then it is compressing all the js of my webapp dir.
I am not understanding what is going wrong.

Comment: What is the value of the property `amss.webapp.dir` set to? Look at the effective pom to see what this resolves to and if it points to the set of files (and the location) you really wanted to.

Comment: This is the target directory for the build.All I want to know is this include tag really works in yui compressor because I want to compress only selected js.

Answer (score 1):

this part:

```
<includes>
     <include>${amss.webapp.dir}/impl/amss9/widgets/**/*.js</include>
</includes>
```

will not help you. Instead, you have to use something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compress</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>        
  <configuration>
    <gzip>true</gzip>
    <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
    <sourceDirectory>app/assets/javascripts</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/public/javascripts</outputDirectory>
    <aggregations>
      <aggregation>
        <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
        <insertNewLine>false</insertNewLine>
        <output>${basedir}/public/javascripts/application.js</output>
        <inputDir>${basedir}/public/javascripts/</inputDir>
        <includes>
          <include>jquery-1.7.1.min.js</include>
          <include>arborjs/arbor.js</include>
          <include>arborjs/arbor-graphics.js</include>
          <include>bootstrap.min.js</include>
          <include>application.js</include>
        </includes>
      </aggregation>
    </aggregations>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```